# Javascript recursion does not cover all elements

Tags: javascript, html

I have build a reqursion with javascript which is supposed to run of all elements of an HTML code and outputs a tree of the HTML ELEMENTS by their hierarchy.

**The html code:**

```
<body>
<p id = "asdgadsfgasdf"><h1>as<strong>asdfasdf</strong>dfasdf</h1></p>
<table id = "table1">
        <tr id = "tr1">
        <td id = "try1" style="background-color:green;"><p id="ChosenColor3"> html file1</p></td>
        <tr id = "trNotFounded">
            <td id = "t1"><p id="Choor3"> html file2</p></td>
        </tr>
        </tr>
        <tr  ></tr>
        <tr>
        <td id = "try2"><p id="ch4"> css file</p></td>
        <td><button id="bestRated3" onclick = arrayTest()> ב.מ </button></td>
        <td><button id="submitForm" onclick = submit()> end</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id = "try6"><h1 id = "Cr5"> text </h1></td>
        <td><h1 id="Chose111">aasdfasdf</h1></td>
        <td><p id = "1234"> hello111   <span>Here is the problem1</span>   <b>  Here     is the problem2</b>hiii</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<p id = "tr5"> hello </p>
</body>
```

**the JAVASCRIPT CODE:**

```
var z1 = document.body.childNodes;
var level = "";
getChildsArea(z1);

function getChildsArea(z) {
        if (z.length > 1) {
          for (i=0; i<z.length; i++){
        if (z[i].nodeType == 1) {
            console.log(level + z[i].nodeName + " CLIENT Area: " + z[i].clientWidth*z[i].clientHeight + " ID: " + z[i].getAttribute('id'));
            if ((z[i].childNodes.length == 0) || ((z[i].childNodes.length == 1 && z[i].childNodes[0].nodeType != 1))) {
                continue;
             }

             else{
                   for (k=0; k<z[i].childNodes.length; k++) {
                    if(z[i].childNodes[k].nodeType == 1) console.log(level + "childs: " + z[i].childNodes[k].nodeName
                                             + " ID: " + z[i].childNodes[k].getAttribute('id'));
                    }
                   level = level + "  ";
                   getChildsArea(z[i].childNodes);
                   level = level.substring(0, level.length - 2)
            }
        }   
          }
        }
        else if (z.length == 1 && z[0].nodeType == 1) {
            console.log(level + z[0].nodeName + " CLIENT Area: " + z[0].clientWidth*z[0].clientHeight + " ID: " + z[0].getAttribute('id'));
        }
  }
```

**The output (by console log):**

```
P CLIENT Area: 0 ID: asdgadsfgasdf
H1 CLIENT Area: 49136 ID: null 
childs: STRONG ID: null 
  STRONG CLIENT Area: 0 ID: null 
TABLE CLIENT Area: 83448 ID: table1  
childs: TBODY ID: null  
  TBODY CLIENT Area: 83448 ID: null
  childs: TR ID: tr1  
  childs: TR ID: trNotFounded  
  childs: TR ID: null  
  childs: TR ID: null  
  childs: TR ID: null  
    TR CLIENT Area: 13176 ID: tr1  // THIS ONE IS OK
    childs: TD ID: try1  
      TD CLIENT Area: 1232 ID: try1  
      childs: P ID: ChosenColor3  
        P CLIENT Area: 1080 ID: ChosenColor3  
    TR CLIENT Area: 16470 ID: null // THIS ONE IS OK

   // where are 3 more ??

    childs: TD ID: try2  
    childs: TD ID: null  
    childs: TD ID: null  
      TD CLIENT Area: 1568 ID: try2  
      childs: P ID: ch4  
        P CLIENT Area: 1080 ID: ch4  
      TD CLIENT Area: 3752 ID: null  
      childs: BUTTON ID: bestRated3  
        BUTTON CLIENT Area: 558 ID: bestRated3  
      TD CLIENT Area: 9660 ID: null  
      childs: BUTTON ID: submitForm  
        BUTTON CLIENT Area: 594 ID: submitForm
```

**THE PROBLEM:**
not all elements are shown at the console log, for instance, you can see "TBODY" element, which have 5 (TR element) children, but only 2 children are represented in the tree.
I'm sure I have missed up something in my code, can someone please help?
Thanks,
Doron

Comment: please make a jsfiddle with your code so that we can test it.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid... you cannot have nested `<tr></tr>` tags.  Plus I would doubt that `onclick = submit()` would work without quotes (i.e `onclick="submit()"`)

Comment: `<tbody></tbody>` isn't in your code in the first place, so you can't be sure that every browser will generate the same code. You should sanatize your HTML code first.

Comment: I know the HTML code is not perfect and this is my intention. The code  is supposed to run over big number of websites which I suppose some of them are using "bad" HTML writing. As you can see "tbody" does not appear in my code but the JS code reveales it, and this is good. I have copied the code into jsfiddle but I'm not sure how to see the console log and check if it working.. I hope you can manage with that. link: http://jsfiddle.net/9zpnh/

Comment: Sorry, but if the HTML is invalid, how do you expect the browser to magically deal with it in the way **you** expect it to? Sounds like you're onto a losing battle from the off

Comment: freefaler - I know it's sounds weird, but it is very complicated to explain, this is part of big code that I'm writing and these are my needs. anyway - thank you for your time.

Comment: Not a problem @Doran, good luck.  (BTW, on SO if you want to message somebody directly, who is not the writer of the post, use the "at" sign, which will notify that user of a message)

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote you a fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/ppbjT/1/

This recursion shows all elements. Embed your logging.

```
function findAllElements(element){
    spacing+=spaceValue;
    if(element.tagName){
        console.log(spacing+element.tagName+(element.id? ("#"+element.id):"")+element.className? ("."+element.className):""));
        var children =element.childNodes;
        for (var i= 0;i<children.length;i++){
            findAllElements(children[i])
        }
    }
    spacing=spacing.slice(0,-spaceValue.length);
```

}

Comment: This is almost working.. the problem is - as you can see in my HTML code there is TR tag inside TR tag, and your code outputs both tr in the same level.. I have check this issue with the DTD of html and this is illegal writing (TR can only contain TD or TH). but as I described below, my code is running over big number of websites which some of them using illegal writing and I want to cover them all..

Comment: if you open element inspector in chrome, in will show that my logger is correct, because chrome is fixing these issues automatically, and there is no way to get initial order, anyway page will render correctly, if you'll test in IE 8, it will output data as you wish, coz it has no fixing feature

Answer (score 0):

As per [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18889763/javascript-recursion-does-not-cover-all-elements#comment27880889_18889763), the main issue is that your HTML is invalid... you cannot have nested `<tr></tr>` tags.

You should also make sure that attributes use either single or double quotes for the value, and do not have spaces between them (although this is not strictly necessary, it's a good practise to get into).  For instance

```
onclick = submit()
```

Should be replaced with

```
onclick="submit();"
```